# Show div When Page Scrolls to 100px

Tags: jquery, html

I want to show a DIV when page scrolls to bottom e.g. say 100px down from top. I'm using the code below

The HTML

```
<div class="scroll_div">Hello World!</div>
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function ($) {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (y > 100) {
        $('.scroll_div').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scroll_div').fadeOut();
    }

});
```

and CSS

```
body {
    height:1600px;
}

.scroll_div{
    display: none;
}
```

Please help

Comment: Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zYYZn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are using old version of minified jQuery. It has few deprecated code(s) that needs to be replace with some new functions, e.g. it has a known `returnValue` deprected code that needs to be replace by `preventDefault`.

I'd suggest you to search the code I mentioned and try replacing with the sugested code.

Comment: Amazing answer!! Yes there was that deprected code and i changed and it works :) Thank you once again!!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$(document).scroll(function () { // remove "$"
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();        
    if (y > 100) {
        $('.scroll_div').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('.scroll_div').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4pfP/2/)

Comment: Just checked, does not work for me in chrome. Just for curiosity. - @Hiral

Comment: it works, but the OP does not want to use the global `$` which this solution does not solve this issue.

Comment: @NathanLee: I am checking it on 32.0.1700.14 beta. And I guess the version is not an issue. I have used similar logic before and worked well prior to 30 even.

Comment: Thanks Hiral, its working in jsfiddle but I don't know why its not working on the page I'm implementing this on :/ Could this be a conflict somewhere?

Comment: I repasted your code on a jsbin and it showed me an error on `console.log(y)` and needed a semicolon addition. I added the same i.e `console.log(y);` and it worked. http://jsbin.com/IbuXAzIZ/1 - @Hiral

Comment: May be. Try `$(window).scroll` instead of `(document)`. hope that works.

Comment: @user2854563 in which browser? which version?

Comment: @Hiral: In both chrome and FF, it works in jsfiddle but not when I implement this on my webpage. Could you please post the link of the jquery library I should I use for this? I'm using minified version of jquery but not sure if it works with it or not..

Comment: @user2854563 have you given fixed/absolute position to `scroll_div`? div wont be visible otherwise. I suggest you to console/alert on scroll function and see the value of `scrollTop()`

Comment: Yes I've given, here is my complete CSS style: `.scroll_div{
display: none;
width: 90%;
opacity: 0.7;
color: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #403F3F;
font-size: 11px;
font-family: Tahoma;
padding: 7px 9px;
background: #4D4D4D;
border-radius: 2px;
text-decoration: none;
position: absolute;
top: 1px;
margin: 0;
text-align: left;
z-index: 1;
}`

Comment: Chrome console shows this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'scrollTop'`

Answer (score 1):

The parameter passed to an event handler represents the event object. Try this instead:

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function (e) {
```

If you want to use `$` inside your event handler, wrap the handler in another function that takes in the jQuery object:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).scroll(function(e) {
        //...
    });
})(jQuery);
```